# Gzip only files containing "*foo*" over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, gzip

In a directory, is it possible to gzip only files containing "foo"? I can find them all by  `find . -name "*foo*"` but i need a way to archive them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean archive into a single tar file? Not individual .gz files?
Try this: (assumes there aren't too many files)

```
find . -name "*foo*" | xargs tar cvzf archive.tar.gz
```

An alternative is to do something like:

```
find . -name "*foo*" > list.txt
tar cvzf archive.tar.gz -T list.txt #(works only with gnu tar, not bsd i think)
```

Comment: `-L` means follow symbolic links, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you, find . -name "*foo*" | xargs tar cvzf archive.tar.gz works!

Comment: Then you don't need the intermediate step, either.  `find... | tar -T - -czf archive.tar.gz`